# angular2 drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

Trying to have a drag and drop feature in my app I have seen jquery ui DnD which I think is fine but is there an angular2 way of doing it? Also want to connect objs like how flow-based design works.

I know there's ng2-dragula but that only drag obj from  one container to another and won't allow you position the obj anywhere on the canvas.

idea of the feature I'm trying to do.
http://www.jointjs.com/rappid#ebe312a3-01da-437c-825a-555323a7bb52

Comment: not quite as I mentioned that I know ng2-dragula exist but that just DnD from container to container.

Comment: There isnt a ready api for ur use case, i prefer you build one.

Comment: @PratikKelwalkar Yeah building it from scratch seems to be the way to go, found something in d3js as well which might fit my need. Will update this to share my findings soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find an angular 2 library that fits your requirements you should consider using a non-angular2 alternative. So if the drag and drop library of JQuery ui works for you, use it!

It's difficult to find complete libraries in Angular 2 since it does not has a final version yet.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **angular2-grid**. Angular 2 grid is a drag/drop/resize grid-based plugin directive for Angular 2.

[Demo available here](https://bmorton.co.uk/angular/)

See if this helps.

Comment: That's one option but its limits you where to move your object.